# Spring - Hibernate: Unable to Save object data to table with HibernateTemplate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have looked throughout stackoverflow and I can not seem to find an answer to my query pertaining to saving Created Objects to a Database Table (MySQL) using the HibernateTemplate. I am using Hibernate 5 and the latest iteration of Spring 5.0.7. I am very new to Spring-Hibernate here is the code I have written thus far:

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id = "dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/edureka?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=Europe/Amsterdam&amp;useSSL=false" />
        <property name="username" value="admin" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id= "mySessionFactory" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>mobilephone.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id = "dao" class = "co.module12.MobilePhoneDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref = "mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Hibernate Mapping File (mobilephone.hbm.xml):**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
" - //Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name = "co.module12.MobilePhone" table="mobiles">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="increment"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="manfacturer" />
        <property name="name" />
        <property name="price" />
        <property name="colour" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**POJO class (Java Bean) MobilePhone.java:**

```
package co.module12;

/**
 *
 * @author NetBeans
 */
public class MobilePhone {
    private String manfacturer;
    private String colour;
    private Double price;
    private String name;
    private Integer id;


    public MobilePhone() {

    }

    public String getManfacturer() {
        return manfacturer;
    }

    public void setManfacturer(String manfacturer) {
        this.manfacturer = manfacturer;
    }

    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }

    public void setColour(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }




}
```

**MobilePhoneDAO.java:**

```
package co.Module12;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


/**
 *
 * @author NetBeans
 */
public class MobilePhoneDAO {
    HibernateTemplate template;
    SessionFactory factory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
       template = new HibernateTemplate(factory);
    }


    public void saveMobile(MobilePhone phone) {
        template.setCheckWriteOperations(false);
        template.save(phone);
        System.out.println(phone.getId());
        System.out.println(phone.getManfacturer());
        System.out.println(phone.getName());

    }

    public void updateMobile(MobilePhone phone) {
        template.update(phone);
    }

    public void deleteMobile(MobilePhone phone) {
        template.delete(phone);
    }

}
```

**Main File:**

```
package co.Module12;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

/**
 *
 * @author NetBeans
 */
public class Module12MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        MobilePhoneDAO dao = (MobilePhoneDAO)context.getBean("dao");

        /*Create Mobile Phone One to Map to mySQL database*/
        MobilePhone samsungOne = new MobilePhone();
        samsungOne.setColour("black");
        samsungOne.setManfacturer("Samsung");
        samsungOne.setName("Galaxy S9+");
        samsungOne.setPrice(55158.25);
        samsungOne.setId(1001);
        dao.saveMobile(samsungOne);

        /*Create Mobile Phone Two to Map to mySQL database*/
        MobilePhone lgPhone = new MobilePhone();
        lgPhone.setColour("gray");
        lgPhone.setManfacturer("LG");
        lgPhone.setName("G7");
        lgPhone.setPrice(58782.25);
        lgPhone.setId(1002);
        dao.saveMobile(lgPhone);

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The problem is that the objects are not being saved to the table "mobiles" via the HibernateTemplate.

Comment: Is there any output/error msg etc. ?

Comment: @Emre, no there are none.

Comment: you are using XML based configuration. I don't find any `transactionManager` bean defined moreover to use `@transaction` you need  to specify `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManagerBeanName"/>`

Comment: @Kid101, that did not work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Spring "@Transactional" (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) annotation to your DAO methods.

What is likely happening (though I cannot test it out at the moment as I currently don't have the proper jars for your db) is that although your code does execute the "save" methods (as you might determine if you are getting no errors and can put a debugger in your DAO), Hibernate is probably set to do what is called "auto-flush" by default.  This means that Hibernate decides when to flush the records to the database, but since there is no transaction, Hibernate doesn't bother to ever invoke this.  Placing the "@Transactional" annotation binds the save call to a Spring transaction in which the Hibernate Session is also bound, meaning that when the transaction closes, the Session is notified to close, and it should flush.

Update: This is the error I got running your example stock with an H2 datasource:

```
BUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate - Could not retrieve pre-bound Hibernate session
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:699)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:344)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:326)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:640)
    at co.module12.MobilePhoneDAO.saveMobile(MobilePhoneDAO.java:23)
    at co.module12.Module12MainClass.main(Module12MainClass.java:23)
```

However, there needs to be an update to your Spring context file to allow transactions to work at all.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/><!-- a PlatformTransactionManager is still required -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <!-- (this dependency is defined somewhere else) -->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

This is taken from the example from:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

I got this code to work on an H2 datasource, MySQL shouldn't be too different.  However, three cautions:

1. Check your imports - it must be the *Spring* Transactional, not javax!
2. Price is monetary - so you should map to BigDecimal, not Double, as precision is important.
3. You should rely on the save() call to generate your ID - don't generate the ID beforehand.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the @Transactional annotation did not resolve the problem. (I added the annotation to all of the DAO methods (save, update and delete)).

Comment: Updated when I was able to test with a data source.

Comment: @Al-geBra any luck with this?